# Through or because of

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is it acceptable to say “John earned a medal of Bravery **through** his actions”?

It would makes sense to prefer ‘because of’ instead of ‘through’ but is this acceptable or simply poor grammar?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would say

> John earned a Medal of Bravery *for* his actions

However, of the two choices you provided, "Through his actions" is preferable, but it might sound better to start the sentence with that:

> Through his actions, John earned a Medal of Bravery